# Jetty stops loading stylesheets from Grails application after a few days of running

Tags: java, css, grails, jetty, grails-2.0

I am running Grails on a Jetty server hosted on a Rackspace cloud VM.   After deploying and starting the app, everything runs just fine.   After several days, the CSS style sheet just stops loading.  I can still successfully navigate to the page, and all the links work.  All of the data is also there, it's just not styled.

Rebooting Jetty fixes the problem, but I don't want to have to reboot every few days.  What could be causing this issue?

For reference, the url is http://www.flashbandproject.org .  I have not rebooted the server yet, though I may do this in the next few hours (so you may or may not see the CSS ).

Comment: URI
    /static/css/style.css
Class
    java.io.FileNotFoundException
Message
    /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-root.war-_-any-/grails-resources/css/style.css (No such file or directory)

Comment: Yes, I see that also, but when I first bring up the site, I don't get the file not found.   Why would a CSS file suddenly disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if your problem is the same, but my issue was that the /tmp directory was being cleared out periodically by a cron job. (See explanation here: https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared ) By default, Jetty expands war files into the /tmp directory. If you simply create a /work directory under $JETTY_HOME, Jetty will use that directory instead for the expanded war.